# how do i compute and display the value of a investment for each of the next 5 years

Tags: java

i believe i am making a math formula error here the code seems to work but the math is coming out completely wrong.

```java
   public static void main (String [] args) {
       
       Scanner sam = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.print("enter initial investment: ");
       double principal = sam.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("enter initial rate:  ");
       double Rate = sam.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("Enter the time:  ");
       double time = sam.nextDouble();
       Rate = (1 + (Rate / 100));
       double interest = (principal * Rate);
       for (int i=1; i < time; i++) {
           System.out.printf("year %d \n", i);
           System.out.printf("interest: %f \n", interest);
           double amount = (principal + interest);
           interest = (amount * Rate);
           System.out.printf("value: %f \n", amount);
       }
    }
```

Output:

```
enter initial investment: 1000
enter initial rate:  5
Enter the time:  5
year 1 
interest: 1050.000000 
value: 2050.000000 
year 2 
interest: 2152.500000 
value: 3152.500000 
year 3 
interest: 3310.125000 
value: 4310.125000 
year 4 
interest: 4525.631250 
value: 5525.631250
```

Comment: Can we see some output?

Comment: Please add more details how are we suppose to guess your expected output ?

Comment: appologies added output

Comment: Please explain the logic and mention the expected output

Comment: @SamikSood The interest for the first year in this example should be 50.00 (5%), not 1050 (105%) what you have calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue is with setting Rate to `1 + Rate / 100`, that is the rate is over 100%.  Also, the interest is not accrued to the principal properly.

Also, it's better to avoid using `double` for monetary arithmetics.

So the fixed code may look like:

```java
       Scanner sam = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.print("enter initial investment: ");
       int principal = sam.nextInt() * 100; // in cents
       System.out.print("enter initial rate:  ");
       int Rate = sam.nextInt(); // percent
       System.out.print("Enter the time:  ");
       int time = sam.nextInt();
       
       int interest = (principal * Rate) / 100;
       for (int i=1; i < time; i++) {
           System.out.printf("year %d \n", i);
           System.out.printf("interest: %s \n", interest / 100.0);
           principal += interest; // adding interest
           interest = (principal * Rate) / 100;
           System.out.printf("value: %s\n", principal / 100.0);
       }
```

Output

```
enter initial investment: 1000
enter initial rate:  5
Enter the time:  5
year 1 
interest: 50.0 
value: 1050.0
year 2 
interest: 52.5 
value: 1102.5
year 3 
interest: 55.12 
value: 1157.62
year 4 
interest: 57.88 
value: 1215.5
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i managed to fix it thanks to the answers by @alex rudenko  here's how i did it
'''

```
   Scanner sam = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.print("enter initial investment: ");
   double principal = sam.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("enter initial rate:  ");
   double Rate = sam.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter the time:  ");
   double time = sam.nextDouble();
   Rate /= 100.0;
   double interest = (principal * Rate);
   for (int i=1; i < time; i++) {
       System.out.printf("year %d \n", i);
       System.out.printf("interest: %f \n", interest);
       principal  = (principal + interest);
       interest = (principal*Rate); 
       System.out.printf("value: %f \n", principal);
   }
}
```

'''

output:
enter initial investment: 1000
enter initial rate:  5
Enter the time:  5
year 1
interest: 50.000000
value: 1050.000000
year 2
interest: 52.500000
value: 1102.500000
year 3
interest: 55.125000
value: 1157.625000
year 4
interest: 57.881250
value: 1215.506250